# Change style of NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am doing a `tableview` with code and I need to apply any `styles`  with a part of one `cell`, and how the `cell` are a `label` in few words I need to change styles in a part of a `label`, my `label` are composed for one `String` which are composed for many `strings` and I need to change the `backgroundColor` and the color of the letters for one of these `Strings`, in summary, I need to change the font of a `NSString`, I search in **Google** for that and I only find that the only solution to do that is use `NSAttributedString` and I tried a lot of that with many examples and none go to me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: An NSString has no attributes, just characters.  Try harder with NSAttributedString, and show your work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `NSMutableAttributedString`

An `NSAttributedString` object manages character strings and associated sets of attributes (for example, font and kerning) that apply to individual characters or ranges of characters in the string.

```
NSMutableAttributedString * string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"firstsecondthird"];
[string addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor blueColor] range:NSMakeRange(0,5)];
[string addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor yellowColor] range:NSMakeRange(5,6)];
[string addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor greenColor] range:NSMakeRange(11,5)];
```

for more details please refer [`NSMutableAttributedString`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/index.html)

Comment: The code don't go for me, instead of show the text with the concrete style, show this "first{NSColor="UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 1 1";}second{..." without any style.

Comment: what iOS version did you check that on?

Comment: Did you do `cell.label.attributedText = string;`? It seems that you put the [(attributed)string description] instead.